# Check if bluetooth is enabled using an Android application

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to check if bluetooth is enabled in a device using an Android application.
I used the .isEnabled method. But there is an error. I found out (by commenting lines) that the error is in .isEnabled method. Can you pls help me to figure this out?

```
final BluetoothAdapter bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String status = "Bluetooth";

        if(bluetooth != null) {
            if (bluetooth.isEnabled()) {
                String mydeviceaddress = bluetooth.getAddress();
                String mydevicename = bluetooth.getName();
                status = ("Address "+ mydeviceaddress + " Name" + mydevicename);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + status + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                status = ("Bluetooth not enabled");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + status + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + status + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

This has worked best for me:

```
/**
 * Check for Bluetooth.
 *
 * @return true if Bluetooth is available.
 */
public boolean isBluetoothAvailable() {
    final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    return bluetoothAdapter != null 
        && bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled() 
        && bluetoothAdapter.getState() == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON;
}
```

Comment: Just one thing, why is that method taking a Context object, when is no really using it at all?

Comment: @hmartinezd Good eye. It is now fixed.

Answer (score 6):

Try this.

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
    // Device does not support Bluetooth
} else {
    if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        // Bluetooth is not enabled
    }
}
```

in your `AndroidManifest.xml File` add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

Comment: @Saku what are the errors ? update your post and put error details.

Comment: A 'Force Close' appears. Since the emulator does not support Bluetooth i tried in an actual tab. So i can't give precise exceptions or error messages

Comment: @Saku Write Log File and track error massages. then you can sea errors occurred.

Comment: If bluetooth permission is only needed for this detection, don't forget to set it NOT required: <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="false" />

Answer (score 3):

Jared Burrows answer seems like the correct one, however I had to add one addition before it started working. I had to check the Bluetooth state.

```
public static boolean isBluetoothAvailable() {
    final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    return (bluetoothAdapter != null &&
            bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled() &&
            bluetoothAdapter.getState() == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just:

```
...
return mBluetoothAdapter != null && mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled();
```