# android check if bluetooth is on/off

Tags: android, bluetooth

I made a sms reciever text to speach, they talk only if bluetooth is on and connect in boardcast. I look on google and the tutorial found tell me how to connect but i can't find the right one to check if is on or off. I start with

```
if (bluetooth == on){
//do some stuff.
}
else {
// do other stuff
```

This is my code if it may help you to understand :

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;


 public class RecevoirSms extends BroadcastReceiver
{
final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();          
    final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");         
    for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {                      
    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);     
    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();            
    String senderNum = phoneNumber;             
    String Message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();   

 if (senderNum.contains("3330") || senderNum.contains("5149921188") || senderNum.contains("9000"))   {
}

 else {

    String word = senderNum;
    String remove ="+1";
    String Numero = (removeWords(word, remove));
    MemoireCourtTerme.Nsms =  Numero;  
    MemoireCourtTerme.Message = Message;

    if (Message.contains("eva") && Message.contains("?") || Message.contains("Eva") && Message.contains("?")){
       Intent i2 = new Intent(context,EvaSms.class); 
       i2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       context.startActivity(i2); 
    }

    else {
           MemoireCourtTerme.Mode = "SmsRecu";
           MemoireCourtTerme.ReponceEva = "Vous avez reçu un nouveau message voulez vous l'écoutez?";
           MemoireCourtTerme.ReponceEvaDuree = "5000";
           Intent i2 = new Intent(context,Parole.class); 
           i2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           context.startActivity(i2); 
        }


            }                         
}
}
public static String removeWords(String word, String remove){
    return word.replace(remove, "");
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if bluetooth is enabled using an Android application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242519/check-if-bluetooth-is-enabled-using-an-android-application)

Comment: This question has already been answered, refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11242618/1225413

Comment: no i need check if bluetooth adapter is connected

Answer (score 5):

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
    // Device does not support Bluetooth
} else {
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        // Bluetooth is not enable :)
    }
}
```

and use permissions:-

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

**For HeadSet Profile ControL**

```
BluetoothHeadset mBluetoothHeadset;

// Get the default adapter
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

// Establish connection to the proxy.
mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy(context, mProfileListener, BluetoothProfile.HEADSET);

private BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener mProfileListener = new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener() {
    public void onServiceConnected(int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy) {
        if (profile == BluetoothProfile.HEADSET) {
            mBluetoothHeadset = (BluetoothHeadset) proxy;
        }
    }
    public void onServiceDisconnected(int profile) {
        if (profile == BluetoothProfile.HEADSET) {
            mBluetoothHeadset = null;
        }
    }
};

// ... call functions on mBluetoothHeadset

// Close proxy connection after use.
mBluetoothAdapter.closeProfileProxy(mBluetoothHeadset);
```

Comment: this code work but only if bluetooth mode is on. I need to know about bluetooth headset is connect

Comment: @MichelSurik u wants to check weather headset is connected or not?

Comment: yes the text to speach with headset this is good but without is not usefull

Comment: @MichelSurik can You Please tell me what You exactly want

Comment: i want to check if the bluetooth adapter is connected and on because if is on the text to speach read my sms if is off nothing else hapend

Answer (score 0):

An alert will then appear allowing the user to respond to the request. There is a `BluetoothAdapter` function `enable()`, but the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#enable%28%29) explicitly discourages using it except in specific circumstances.

```
BluetoothAdapter BluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Bluetooth not available",Toast.LENGHT_LONG).show();
}
else{  
if (BluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Bluetooth is ON",Toast.LENGHT_LONG).show();
}
else{
Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
boolean retval = mAudioManager.isBluetoothScoOn();
```

Answer (score 0):

Like that

```
val filter = IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)
 registerReceiver(bluetoothChangeReceiver, filter)


 private val bluetoothChangeReceiver: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent) {
            val action = intent.action

            if (action == BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED) {
               val state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE,
                        BluetoothAdapter.ERROR)
                when (state) {
                    BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF -> Log.i(TAG, "Bluetooth off")
                    BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF -> Log.i(TAG, "Turning Bluetooth off...")
                    BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON -> Log.i(TAG, "Bluetooth on")
                    BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON -> Log.i(TAG, "Turning Bluetooth on...")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```